# In Shotwell, how can I delete files that have been removed from the library?

Tags: shotwell

I emptied the Shotwell bin, and accidentally chose the "Remove from Library" option, rather than the "Remove and Trash" option. How can I now delete the files permanently from disc that are no longer in the library? (There were 91 files in the bin.) I'm using Shotwell v0.22.0.

Comment: What version of Shotwell are you running? You can get this information by Clicking Help->About. Once you have it please [edit] that information into your question.